# Django files storage: How to get base url of media file?

Tags: django, storage, gcloud, base-url

I'm using gcloud wrapped into django-storages logic. I have never feed the service with a url path of my bucket: only provided DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE and GS_BUCKET_NAME which are the name of my glcoud project and storage.

My question is: How can I get the full url of my images? My images are saved with a relative url, which make sens into the DB. But I can't found any right documentation about how you can get the base url of the django.core.files.storage collection of object storage.

Some filestorage objects ask a valid relative image url in order to retrieve the full path. But this is not what I want: I just want to know (programatically) the base url of my (only one) bucket. The template `{% image item.image %}` is able to generate the full url, but from the code side view it seems totally obscure for me.

Any help or advice?

Comment: Do you mind sharing why do you want this information?

Comment: I'm writting a graphQL implementation of my django models. Some of them return images object with relative url, but I need to recreate the full url path.

Comment: How about calling the backend storage method in order to get the full URL?

Comment: Django default_storage library is able to reconstruct it (when it save or display the images). I was wondering if this information was opaque or easy to access since the documentation is kind of obscure. And the gcloud backend storage is everything but not transparent. Still, default_storage is able to get the information.

Comment: `default_storage` in you case IS an instance of the gcloud backend storage. I guess it is an instance of [Storage](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/files/storage/#the-storage-class) so your API probably should be serializing the result of `default_storage.url(item.image)` instead of `item.image`.

Comment: Yes thanks. This is exactly what I wanted. I can retrieve the full path now. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is easier to get the full URL than get the prefix and join the relative part of the URL that is stored by some endpoints.

The base class for Django file storage backend is [Storage](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/files/storage/#the-storage-class). This class has an `url` method that is likely to be implemented in any cloud storage backend worth its salary:

> **url(name)**
>   Returns the URL where the contents of the file referenced by name can be accessed. For storage systems that don’t support access by URL this will raise NotImplementedError instead.

So just serialize the result of this method in your API. For example if you have your model already serialized as a dict named "data" you can update the "image" field from relative to absolute using:

```
relative_url = data.get("image")
full_url = relative_url and default_storage.url(relative_url)
data.update({"image": full_url})
```

Comment: Why `and` in the 2nd line? Should it be `relative_url or default_storage.url(relative_url)` ?