# Django open excel.xlsx with openpyxl from Google Cloud Storage

Tags: django, excel, django-rest-framework, google-cloud-storage, openpyxl

I need to open a .xlsx file from my bucket on Google Cloud Storage, the problem is I get :FileNotFoundError at /api/ficha-excel

[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'ficha.xlsx'

These are the settings from my bucket.

```
UPLOAD_ROOT = 'reportes/'
MEDIA_ROOT = 'reportes'
```

These are the route bucket/reportes/ficha.xlsx

[image]

This is the code of my get function:

```
    directorio = FileSystemStorage("/reportes").base_location
    os.makedirs(directorio, exist_ok=True)
    # read
    print("Directorios: ", directorio)
    plantilla_excel = openpyxl.load_workbook(f"{directorio}/ficha.xlsx")
    print(plantilla_excel.sheetnames)
    currentSheet = plantilla_excel['Hoja1']
    print(currentSheet['A5'].value)
```

What is the problem with the path? I can't figure out.

Comment: As per this [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/files/storage/#the-filesystemstorage-class), the location parameter of FileSystemStorage class needs to have a absolute path to the directory that will hold the files. The location defaults to the value of your MEDIA_ROOT setting. I suggest you try setting both MEDIA_ROOT and location with the absolute path for eg. 'gs://mybucket/folder/file.xlsx'. Also give proper permissions for reading/viewing storage objects.

Comment: @PriyashreeBhadra what about using default_storage? i wll still need to define media_root as absolute path?

Comment: How i can edit to absolute path?  this are my settings:                                              
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.gcloud.GoogleCloudStorage'
GS_PROJECT_ID = 'green-carrier-xxxxxx'
GS_BUCKET_NAME = 'inversiones-admision'
UPLOAD_ROOT = 'reportes/'
MEDIA_ROOT = 'reportes'

MEDIA_URL = 'https://storage.googleapis.com/{}/'.format(GS_BUCKET_NAME)                          and as i understand i have to put this on the views?                            plantilla_excel = openpyxl.load_workbook("//inversiones-admision/ficha.xlsx")

Comment: I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40461817/15803365) should answer your question. Try and let me know if it worked.

Comment: i already do that, i can perfect open files on my bucket with django-storages, and default_storage, the problem is that i need to read the file with the openpyxl and i cant extract or get the path of the opened file.

Comment: Thanks for clearing it out. [Storage class also has an url method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48691865/15803365) that is likely to be implemented in any cloud storage backend but it returns the URL where the contents of the file referenced by name can be accessed. For storage systems that don’t support access by URL this will raise NotImplementedError instead. Note : I am just trying to help you. These solutions are not tested. I will need your help to try and test them.

Comment: Hey Nuevakenia,were you able to solve the issue?

Comment: not as i expected, i had to open a .xlsx template from my project folder, and then i generate an .excel based on it, i dont know where the files are generated lol, but i cant find it on my bucket or in my project folder, so makedir and filestorage are doing some black magic for me.

Comment: That is strange, can you retry performing the whole setup again with a new bucket?

Comment: Or if you are okay, you can also use pandas for the same.

Comment: What is the output to your print of "directorio"?

Answer (score 1):

The below solution doesn’t use Django FileStorage/Storage classes. It opens a .xlsx file from the Cloud Storage bucket on Google Storage using openpyxl.

**Summary :**

I uploaded the Excel file on GCS, read the Blob data with openpyxl via BytesIO and saved the data in the workbook using the .save() method.

**Steps to Follow :**

Create a Google Cloud Storage bucket. Choose a globally unique name for it. Keep with the defaults and finally enter Create.

Choose an Excel file from your local system and upload it in the bucket using the “Upload files” option.
Once you have the excel file in your bucket, follow the steps below :

- Go to Google Cloud Platform and create a service account (API). Click
  Navigation Menu> APIs & Services> Credentials to go to the screen.
  Then click Manage Service Accounts.
- On the next screen, click Create Service Account.
- Enter the details of the service account for each item.
- In the next section, you will create a role for Cloud Storage. Choose
  Storage Admin (full permission).
- Click the service account you created, click Add Key in the Keys
  field, and select Create New Key.
- Select JSON as the key type and "create" it. Since the JSON file is
  downloaded in the local storage, use the JSON file in the next item
  and operate Cloud Storage from Python.
- We will install the libraries required for this project in Cloud
  Shell  First, install the Google Cloud Storage library with pip
  install to access Cloud Storage:

  `pip install google-cloud-storage`

  Install openpyxl using :

  `pip install openpyxl`
- Create a folder (excel) with the name of your choice in your Cloud editor.
  Create files within it :

  main.py
  JSON key file (the one that got  downloaded in local storage, copy that
  file into this folder)

  excel
  main.py
  ●●●●●●●●●●.json

Write the below lines of code in main.py file :

```
from google.cloud import storage
import openpyxl
import io

#Create a client instance for google cloud storage
client = storage.Client.from_service_account_json('●●●●●●●●●●.json') //The path to your JSON key file which is now 
#Get an instance of a bucket
bucket = client.bucket(‘bucket_name’) //only the bucketname will do, full path not necessary.

##Get a blob instance of a file
blob = bucket.blob(‘test.xlsx') // test.xlsx is the excel file I uploaded in the bucket already.
buffer = io.BytesIO()
blob.download_to_file(buffer)
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(buffer)
wb.save('./retest.xlsx')
```

You will see a file ‘retest.xlsx’ getting created at the same folder in Cloud Editor.

Comment: sorry about no responding this, i really aprecciate your time and effort and concern with your help, im close to the deadline of this project so that is why i dont have tested and answered, but soon i will. thanks a lot!